# Is it possible to get the number of facebook video views using facebook graph API

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I have Looked at the facebook graph api reference for videos (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video) But I currently don't see any way of getting the number of facebook video views. Is it possible to get the number of facebook video views using this api or any other walkaround?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [insights edge](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/insights) to retrieve video views.

Comment: how we can get the views of the videos user uploaded to his timeline ...?